# LLVM-16 CMake error: CMake is not able to include CMakePolicy.cmake file, which is present at required location

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm

I've downloaded LLVM-16 source from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-16.0.0. After extraction I've a folder as `llvm.16.0.0.src`. I also downloaded `cmake-16.0.0.src.tar.xz` and after extracting, copied the contents of `cmake-16.0.0.src/Modules` to `llvm-16.0.0.src\cmake\modules`. Finally I created a build folder under **llvm.16.0.0.src** and from inside it, I ran the command -

```
cmake ..\ -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_ZLIB=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_BENCHMARKS=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_UTILS=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF -DLLVM_COMMON_CMAKE_UTILS=OFF -Thost=x64 -A x64 -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
```

I get error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/dev/llvm-16.0.0.src/../cmake/Modules/CMakePolicy.cmake
```

the file is present at the location `C:/dev/llvm-16.0.0.src/cmake/Modules/` but still it is complaining.

How to solve it?

I am using Visual Studio 2023 developer command prompt, which has CMake version 3.25.1-msvc1.

Comment: well, it's looking for it at `C:/dev/llvm-16.0.0.src/../cmake/Modules/CMakePolicy.cmake` and you say it's in `C:/dev/llvm-16.0.0.src/cmake/Modules/`. Or did you just mistype?

Comment: I get it now, Its looking for that file outside llvm-16.0.0.src. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is tracked in the following issue ticket: [Open
16.0.0: llvm build wants to use files from outside of the source tree
#61502](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/61502). Related commit where a code change related to this issue was made: [`88d7508`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/88d7508dc479210f07abccb17f0194b66264b125).

There's no resolution to the issue ticket yet. You'll just have to stay subscribed to the issue. I'm also subscribed to it and will update this answer post with what version this gets resolved in.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For now I've removed the code from cmakelist where it is trying to include CMakePolicy.cmake file. Build files got generated successfully and I was able to build clang-tidy which is the only lib I required. Let me know if I am missing anything important by not including CMakePolicy explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure how critical it is to `include` that file. But here are its contents if you're interested: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/cmake/Modules/CMakePolicy.cmake